# From json to image using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas, fabricjs

I am saving a fabricjs canvas on my database as a json. I've got no intention of modifying it, I just want to recover it, resize it and finally create a PNG or JPG image, which I will add in my web page.

By the moment, I've done the following:

- I create a canvas html element and I hide it
- I load de json on it (this works)
- From that canvas, I obtain it's context, I resize it and I get
  the dataURL (I obtain an apparent good url)
- I create an  html element and I match the dataURL with the img src

It seems to work, but the image is transparent. The size its ok but it hasn't got anything inside.
I would like to do this without having to create a canvas element and hidding it.
Something like, create a var on js script, load the json on it, resize it,getting the dataurl and set it on a  element.

```
var exerciseList;

var canvas0 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas0');
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');
var canvas3 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas3');
var canvas4 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas4');

$(document).ready(function () {
    var login = $.session.get("login");

    $.ajax({
        url: backEndpoint + "usuarios/" + login + "/ejercicios",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: "GET"
    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            exerciseList = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < exerciseList.length; i++) {
                addExercise(exerciseList[i],i);
                loadExercise(exerciseList[i],i);
            }

        })
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {


        });
});
var canvas;

function loadExercise(exercise, idx) {
    switch (idx) {
        case 0:
            canvas = canvas0;
            break;
        case 1:
            canvas = canvas1;
            break;
        case 2:
            canvas = canvas2;
            break;
        case 3:
            canvas = canvas3;
            break;
        case 4:
            canvas = canvas4;
            break;
        default:
            console.log("ERROR")
            break;
    }
    canvas.loadFromJSON(exercise.figura, callbackFunction(idx));
}

function callbackFunction(idx) {
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
    //canvas.requestRenderAll(); // It doesnt work with anyone
    var $img = getImage(idx);
    $("#imageContainer"+idx).append($img);
}

function getImage(idx) {

    var width = 343;
    var height = 300;

    var resizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var resizedContext = resizedCanvas.getContext("2d");

    resizedCanvas.width = "" + width;
    resizedCanvas.height = "" + height;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"+idx);

    resizedContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);
    var myResizedData = resizedCanvas.toDataURL();

    return $('<img>').attr("src", myResizedData);

}

function addExercise(exercise, idx) {
    var title = exercise.titulo;
    var description = exercise.descripcion;

    var $exerciseContainer = $('<div>',
        { id: "exerciseContainer"+idx,class: "row ejercicio m-1 rounded border border-secondary" });

    var $imageContainer = $('<div>',
        { id: "imageContainer"+idx, class: "col-7 p-1 border border-secondary" });

    var $bodyContainer = $('<div>',
        { id: "bodyContainer"+idx, class: "col border border-secondary" });

    $('<div>', { class: "row h4 p-1" }).text(title).appendTo($bodyContainer);
    $('<div>', { class: "row  p-1" }).text(resumirDescripcion(description)).appendTo($bodyContainer);

    var $buttonContainer = $('<div>',
        { id: "buttonContainer"+idx, class: "col-1  p-1 border border-secondary" });

    $('<button>', { class: "btn btn-success btn-block p-2" }).appendTo($buttonContainer);
    $('<button>', { class: "btn btn-primary btn-block p-2" }).appendTo($buttonContainer);
    $('<button>', { class: "btn btn-warning btn-block p-2" }).appendTo($buttonContainer);
    $('<button>', { class: "btn btn-info btn-block p-2" }).appendTo($buttonContainer);
    $('<button>', { class: "btn btn-danger btn-block p-2" }).appendTo($buttonContainer);

    $exerciseContainer.append($imageContainer);
    $exerciseContainer.append($bodyContainer);
    $exerciseContainer.append($buttonContainer);

    $("#contenedorEjercicios").append($exerciseContainer);
}
```

I don't know why but calling this function when I press a button it works as it shoulds, but I need it to work when the page is load.

[this is what I get when the page loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2zTR.png)

[this is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS1id.png)

After refactoring some code I obtain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icH3Y.png), but it is the same as before.

Comment: You're probably trying to draw the hidden canvas on the resized one before the image is rendered. When exactly are you calling `appendImage()`?

Comment: I call an ajax function to bring data from database, then I call `functionA()`.
In `functionA()` I first do the `loadFromJSON()` and after it, some lines below, I call `appendImage()`

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: sure, give me some minutes

Comment: Here they are, thoose are my functions

Comment: My guess is that `canvas.loadFromJSON()` might by async; you can pass a callback function as third parameter to it as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/fmgXt/), try moving all code related to `getImage()` inside that callback

Comment: `canvas.loadFromJSON(exercise.figura, callbackFunction(idx));` in this line you are executing `callbackFunction`.

Comment: @Durga what do you mean? Isn't this what you suggested in your answer? Maybe I didn't understand you propperly

Comment: `callbackFunction(idx)`doing this will call your function there it self,

Comment: And shouldn't I call it? Sorry I don't understand what are you reffering to, @Durga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasJSON, function(){
  var url = canvas.toDataURL();
  var $img = getImage();
  $imageContainer.append($img);
});
```

[canvas#loadFromJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) is async for some objects, so better you create your image on callback of `loadFromJSON`.

`canvas.loadFromJSON(exercise.figura, callbackFunction(idx));` In this line doing this will `callbackFunction(idx)` excute `callbackFunction`,

If you want to change the annonymous function to a named function and need to pass a parameter you can do like this.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, () => callbackFunction(exercise,idx))
function callbackFunction(exercise, idx){
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
  var url = canvas.toDataURL();
  var $img = getImage(idx);
  $imageContainer.append($img);
};
```

Comment: I also think async is the key here, but as far as I can tell your code won't work; `getImage()` expects `canvas.renderAll` to have already happened.

Comment: Ah, ok, I've never used fabricjs.

Comment: @ChrisG, just to confirm, did recheck, internally it calls `renderAll()`, though I have added `requestRenderAll()`, if it is not, then on callback again it will render.

Comment: I've tryed what you suggested. I've updated the code, but it stills without working @Durga

Comment: @rubengonzalez96 did a renderAll call, can you check it again?

Comment: @rubengonzalez96 remove your answers, as it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I've got a semi-solution, I know it is not the best practice but it allows me to continue with the project. The code it's the same I wrote in the question, but I changed this:

```
function callbackFunction(idx) {
   canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)();
   setTimeout(function () {
       var $img = getImage(idx);
       $("#imageContainer" + idx).append($img);
   }, 500);
```

}

It is as simple as force to wait half second the canvas is rendered...